# Shimano sora 9 Speed rear derailleur capacity

Tags: derailleur-rear

It's 37T here http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/components11/road/sora1.html

But 31T here
http://www.wiggle.co.uk/shimano-sora-9-speed-rear-derailleur-1/#prodbullets

Why is the difference?

I want to install a 50/34 rings with 11-28 cassette. I have the cassette and RD already but not sure if the RD has the enough capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two 9 speed Sora groups, 3400 (older, with thumb button shifters for upshifts) and 3500 (current, with a paddle for upshifts).

The [Shimano RD-3400](http://www.shimano.com.au/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/SORA/SI_5VY0A_001/SI_5VY0A_001_En_v1_m56577569830614952.pdf) SS has capacity 31t and GS has capacity 37t, both with 11t smallest sprocket, 27t largest sprocket (and 16t chainring and 22t chainring difference respectively).

The [Shimano RD-3500](http://productinfo.shimano.com/#/spec/1.7/ROAD/Rear%20Derailleur) has SS with capacity 37t (front difference <=16) and GS with capacity 41t (front difference <=20). The sprocket ranges have to be (11-14)t to (25-32)t for both.

Wiggle doesn't list which one they're selling, but it looks like they have part of a description from 3400 and part from 3500.

In any case, if you were to buy one, you should get the RD-3500 SS or GS. However, in reality, you can likely use any of them (the specs the manufacturers list can be violated by a tooth or two, normally), at your own risk, of course.